# New /etc/hosts domain not working when called with SSH from terminal

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, dns

I am connecting via ssh to a remote server, as follows:

```
ssh user@128.x.x.x
```

The process works fine as I have the password to get into the server I need to work with.

I wanted to set a name to the IP address, as I would like to make the process smoother and avoid typing and remembering the server IP every single time.

I have edited the `/etc/hosts` file adding the IP and linking to a new name, as follows (second row):

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
128.x.x.x       newname
```

I have flushed the DNS cache with:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sleep 2; echo macOS DNS Cache Reset | say
```

And yet, when calling the ssh server from the terminal via this command:

```
ssh user@newname
```

The command does not work and shows the following error message:

```
ssh: connect to host newname port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any suggestion is welcomed thanks!

Comment: Odd. What happens if you run `ping newname`? Also, have you tried just closing and reopening a terminal window?

Comment: Consider using a Host entry in your ~/.ssh/config file  instead.

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for the answers

@JackGould
I have tried closing and reopening the terminal, nothing changed so far.
If I run `ping newname` the following lines appear: `PING newname (128.x.x.x): 56 data bytes` `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` `Request timeout for icmp_seq 1`  `...`

@MZB 
I have deleted the `newname` lines from `/etc/hosts`, and I have created/edited a `~/.ssh/config` file as follows: `Host newname` `HostName 128.x.x.x` `User user`

I have flushed the cache, closed/reopened the terminal, still not working. Maybe a port or id_rsa (not using either of them)?